# How do you prove this algorithm is optimal?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have this problem: "Given n items with weights varying from 1kg to 10kg, how do you distribute them between the least amount of bags, knowing that each may not hold more than 10kg.".

I've tried solving it by sorting the items from the most to the least heavy, putting them into a bag if they fit, and creating a new bag if they don't. If this is the case, then start again from the most to the least heavy of the remaining items. Here is my code:

```python
list_of_items=raw_input("Input the items' weights (separated by spaces): ").split()

for i in range(len(list_of_items)):
        list_of_items[i]=int(list_of_items[i])

list_of_items.sort()
list_of_items.reverse()

while list_of_items[0]>=10:
        list_of_items=raw_input("You have input an item wheighing over 10kg: ").split()
        for i in range(len(list_of_items)):
                list_of_items[i]=int(list_of_items[i])

        list_of_items.sort()
        list_of_items.reverse()

set_of_bags=[] #In this list we'll store the bags

while(len(list_of_items)!=0):

        weight=0
        bag=[] #creates a new bag

        for item in list_of_items: #cycle copies items to bag
                if item+weight<=10:
                        bag.append(item)
                        weight+=item
        set_of_bags.append(bag) #adds bag to set_of_bags

        for item in bag: #deletes the items that have been put in set_of_bags from original list
                list_of_items.remove(item)

# output
n=0
for bag in set_of_bags:
        n+=1
        weight=0
        for j in bag:
                weight += j
        print "bag #"+str(n), bag, "=>", weight, "kg."
```

I believe this gives the correct answer, but I don't know how to prove it. Any help?

Comment: Sounds like a bin packing problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this is not optimal. In general if you have a nontrivial algorithm that sorts something and then uses a "greedy approach", i.e. chooses something that is minimum or maximum, and you are not sure why this is correct, then it is probably wrong. Especially if you have an optimization problem with integer numbers.

If you have, say, `3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4`, then your algorithm will end up using three bags instead of two.

Your algorithm:

```
Bag 1: 4, 4
Bag 2: 3, 3, 3
Bag 3: 3
```

Optimal:

```
Bag 1: 4, 3, 3
Bag 2: 4, 3, 3
```

Now, just to show that some other heuristics are wrong as well, look at this example: `3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7`. If you go from the lowest to the highest and put `3, 3, 4` in one bag, you end up with four bags instead of three. The same example shows that just because you can fill one bag fully does not mean that you should do so. (However, if you have just two items that combined fill the bag, such as `7` and `3`, then you can put them in a bag and forget about them completely.)

Lastly, look at `3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4`. If you go from the lowest, you get four bags:

```
Bag 1: 3 3 3
Bag 2: 3 4
Bag 3: 4 4
Bag 4: 4
```

If you go from the highest, you get four bags:

```
Bag 1: 4 4
Bag 2: 4 4
Bag 3: 3 3 3
Bag 4: 3
```

However, you can get three bags:

```
Bag 1: 4 3 3
Bag 2: 4 3 3
Bag 3: 4 4
```

Here is what you can do (I omit the proof):

- If you have a 10, put it in a separate bag. Deal with all 10s first.
- If you have a 9, put it in a bag with a 1, if possible, or by itself. Deal with all 9s before continuing.
- If you have a 8, put it in a bag with a 2, if possible, or with two 1s, if possible, or with a single 1, if possible, or by itself. Deal with all 8s before continuing.
- If you have a 7, put it in a bag with a 3 or, if not, with a 2 and a 1 or, if not, with a single 2 or, if not, with as many 1s as you have left. Deal with all 7s before continuing.
- If you have a 6, put if with a 4. If not, *here it gets tricky*...
- At this point all you have left are 6s, 5s, 3s, 2s, 1s. Now, 1s are not important. You can just eliminate them, find the optimal solution, and add them back. Also, if you have at least two 5s, add them together and make a bag (also easy to prove). Thus, you have 6s, 3s, 2s, and at most one 5. If you have a 5, then it has to go with a 3, if possible, and then with a 2 or whatever 1s you have left. If you have no 3s, then your 5 has to go with as many 2s as you have left, and then 1s.
- So now we have 6s, 3s, and 2s left. Now it's like a simple game. You only really have 2s and 3s, that's what is important. Every "6" allows you to take one "3" or two "2"s. After you run out of 6s, you can take five 2s, or a 3 and three 2s, or two 3s and two 2s, or three 3s. Now you can use dynamic programming to find an optimal solution. For example, let `d[i, j, k]` be the minimum number of bags for `i` 2s, `j` 3s, and `k` 6s. There may be better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close, but I don't see you accounting for weights that might be out of order, it looks like if you have items 9kg, 5kg, 1kg. it would add the 9kg item, see the 5kg was too much and skip to the next bag, even though the 1kg item would fit.

I don't know Python optimization as well as most, but i think the fastest would be.

Get the raw values, (10KG, 5KG, 8KG, 2KG, 2KG, 1KG, 10KG, 9KG);
sort/index weight amounts (10KG:2, 9KG:1, 8KG:1, 5KG:1, 2KG:2, 1KG:1)

start filling bags with the heaviest value first, if the weight goes over attempt to add the next largest index until the bag is either A: full or B: at the end of the value index.

Depending on how many values...it MIGHT actually be faster to search the value index backwards and test against the next highest, that way you don't have to iterate as many values for the bigger items. (e.g. 10KG would test 1KG and see that doesn't work. 9KG would test 1KG and see that it works, but also test 2KG and see that it doesn't work, so it takes 1KG as the best value, this is still only 2 iterations instead of the 4 it would take to go from 8, 5, 2 ,1).

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: After adding the largest available weight first, what would happen if you added the smallest available values next?

Comment: good point!! since the process is inherently reductive, that actually would make it faster!